# pySerial inWaiting returns incorrect number of bytes

Tags: python, pyserial

I've got a simple program to test serial functionality. My serial device reacts to two inputs. If the user enters 'a', it responds with 'fg'. If the user enters anything other character/byte, it responds with 'z'. If I send 'b' to the serial device, it will return 'z' just fine. When I send 'a', it should return both 'f' and 'g', so two bytes instead of one.

See code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
    )

ser.write('a')
byteData = ser.read(1) # read one, blocking
moreBytes = ser.inWaiting()

if moreBytes:
    byteData = byteData + ser.read(moreBytes)
    print byteData

print byteData


ser.close()
```

The output is :

```
user@ubuntu:~/code/native$ ./serialTesting.py 
f
```

inWaiting() gives the value of 0, thus it never reads the second byte. If I do a small change to the code, and manually read the two expected bytes, it works fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
    )

ser.write('a')
byteData = ser.read(2) # read two expected bytes for the result 'fg'

print byteData

ser.close()
```

The output is as expected:

```
user@ubuntu:~/code/native$ ./serialTesting.py 
fg
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two decent solutions for this. For either, you'll need to set a timeout like jramirez already suggested:

```
ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=0.5, # IMPORTANT, can be lower or higher
    inter_byte_timeout=0.1 # Alternative
    )
```

### Solution 1: Simple and effective

```
byteData = ser.read(size=800) #Set size to something high
```

This will read up to 800 bytes and will take no more time than the `timeout` you've set. If you've instead set an `inter_byte_timeout`, `read()` will wait up to that amount of time for each *single* byte.

This is a quick solution that will work for cases where you only receive a chunk of data of known maximum size.

### Solution 2: The proper way

```
def read_all(port, chunk_size=200):
    """Read all characters on the serial port and return them."""
    if not port.timeout:
        raise TypeError('Port needs to have a timeout set!')

    read_buffer = b''

    while True:
        # Read in chunks. Each chunk will wait as long as specified by
        # timeout. Increase chunk_size to fail quicker
        byte_chunk = port.read(size=chunk_size)
        read_buffer += byte_chunk
        if not len(byte_chunk) == chunk_size:
            break

    return read_buffer
```

*The code snippet above is licensed under [CC0 1.0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/).*

And then, to read:

```
byteData = read_all(ser)
```

Basically, this will read your data in chunks and wait every time to see if new characters appeared. If less characters were read in the time set by `timeout`, the transmission is considered finished.

This solution will always work, even when you receive a lot of data or if you receive it very slowly.

Answer (score 2):

it could be because the baudrate is really slow. You are processing the inwaiting() call before the second byte gets to the buffer. When you do ser.read(2) it waits(blocks) until 2 bytes have been received thus why it works. Try setting a timeout of 1 second, that should fix your problem.

```
ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1 # add this
    )
ser.write('a')
byteData = ser.read(1) # read one, blocking
byteData += ser.read(ser.inWaiting())

print byteData

ser.close()
```

Comment: I have same problem even using timeout=10. `inWaiting` always reads 0. Using the wxTerminal.py example in pyserial website. Some ideas ?

Comment: I recommend you post a question in SO and someone can help you out. You can post your code and ask a proper question.

Comment: thanks, solved with time.sleep() before inWaiting. Seems the program was faster than the response

Comment: The timeout will do nothing to solve this. It only changes the maximum amount of time `read()` is allowed to take to complete.