# Python reading a constant serial byte length from device

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port

I have a device that sends 23 characters (numbers and alpha's) via RS232 serial in the following format:

$02 T AAAAA Q CCC PP ZZZ S RR I I NFF $0D

(the spaces in the above string are for readability only)

In this 23 character string the:

$02 represents the start of text 2 hex ( I am not sure what hex this is?)

$0D represents a Carriage Return 13 decimal.

I am currently reading this information in via Python mostly successfully but I still feel I am not doing it properly. I rarely program in Python but I have to use a raspberry PI so decided to go with python for the coding.

I setup my RPI serial port with the following function:

```
def setupSerialPort():
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyAMA0',
        baudrate = 9600,
        parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=1,
        xonxoff=0,
        rtscts=0
    )

    return ser
```

From a while loop I read the port as follow:

```
# setup serial port
cSerial = setupSerialPort()

while 1:
    inbuff = cSerial.inWaiting()    

    if inbuff > 0:          

        msgCOM = cSerial.read(inbuff)
        #vMsgCOM = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', msgCOM)

        //insert value into database
        sleep(1)
```

at which point I insert the value "vMsgCOM" or "msgCOM"  string into a mysql database as I read/receive the data. At first I thought that this works pretty well but after a week of data it became clear that I sometimes only capture partial data which splits over two database rows as mentioned previously. I'll give an example:

A correct 23 char string will look like this: K00000E1120002000063B00.

Now sometimes the string is split into two rows like

(1) K00000E11200020

(2) 00063B00

Another variation of the above is the multiple 23 chunks returned as:

K00000E1120002000063B00K00000E1120002000063B00K00000E1120002000063B00

This happens roughly 15 times out of 400 reads for the above.

Can anyone help me in terms of coding to somehow ensure that I always read the buffer correctly when the 23 string arrives. I know timing can be an issue hence the timeout=1 but somehow I read to quickly (or to long) when the read is not complete.

I had a look at this code (haven't tried it yet): [pySerial inWaiting returns incorrect number of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161768/pyserial-inwaiting-returns-incorrect-number-of-bytes) (the def read_all(port, chunk_size=200) function part)

but thought it best to rather ask advice from those in the know.

I have in my code a bit of corrective code to concat the two rows and split the multiple chunk event should these instance(s) happen but I still think it is not the best way of doing things.

If anyone can help me with some example code I will really appreciate it.

Comment: You should invert your code: make the main receiving code wait for a $02 then store incoming data in a buffer, count 23 and check for $0d - and only then store the buffer data in the database. If after 23 there isn’t a $0d then log the error, and revert to waiting for $02, and start again.

Comment: Barny I agree with your methodology. Any python source code to indicate how best to do this?

Comment: Not from me. Write it yourself, is my suggestion. It’s not terribly complicated.